# Update on MongoDB from NodeJS doesnt work

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am able to run the following update command from command line:

```
db.Camera.update({_id:ObjectId("51059ca49c7b280809a2a81e")}, {$set: {"Selected":0}});
```

But the following code in NodeJS doesnt work. When I log item.Selected, I get a non-zero value.

```
exports.findById = function(req, res) {
    var ids = req.params.id.split(",");
    db.collection('Camera', function(err, collection) {
        for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
            collection.findOne({'_id':idArray[i]}, function(err, item) {
                item.Selected += 1;
                console.log('Selected: ' + item.Selected);
                collection.update({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(ids[i])}, item,function(err, updated) {
                  if( err || !updated ) console.log("Not updated");
                  else console.log("Updated");
                });
            });
        }
    });

};
```

In the console, I always see "Not updated".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id inside the loop isn't what you expect because of your use of the variable `i`. These are callbacks, inside a closure. So, when the `findOne` returns, the loop has already finished, meaning it's really not what you expect as `i` will be equal to `ids.length`, for every "Camera."

You can just use the item's `_id` property directly when your code calls update (or anything else you'd like, just don't rely on the loop index, unless you wrap the code within the loop all with a closure which likely isn't necessary).

Something like this ... the query parameter to `update` call is what changed:

```
{'_id':item._id)}
```

Full code:

```
exports.findById = function(req, res) {
    var ids = req.params.id.split(",");
    db.collection('Camera', function(err, collection) {
        for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
            collection.findOne({'_id':ids[i]}, function(err, item) {
                item.Selected += 1;
                console.log('Selected: ' + item.Selected);
                collection.update({'_id':item._id)}, item,function(err, updated) {
                  if( err || !updated ) console.log("Not updated");
                  else console.log("Updated");
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

};

Comment: I hadn't noticed that the variable name idArray didn't match the array variable created by the split either (ids). Try changing that.

Comment: If you add an error check on the findOne call, I think you'd see that nothing was matched.

Answer (score 1):

Problem I had was items ID, if you'll try to log the message you'll get an error saying something about uniqueness about ID blah bla :) so what I did was I saved id of existing item, then deleted it before the update gets called. Same thing was suggested by mongodb devs. so your code would look like:

```
id = item._id
delete item._id
collection.update(_id: id, item, function(err, updated){...}
```

Hope that'll help. And I also would recommend to use Mongoose.